# SonarQube scanner cannot scan Kotlin Jacoco coverage

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

My gradle task jacocoTestReport() works properly and it generates jacocoTestReport.xml. It contains kotlin coverage as expected.

However, if I use SonarQube Scanner 4.0 Jenkins plugin, it fails to send Kotlin part of coverage report. So I cannot find kotlin coverage on Sonarqube dashboard.

I think there is something wrong with my Analysis properties, but I cannot find it.

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=aaaaa123
sonar.projectName=aaaaa123
sonar.projectVersion=${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}

# disable sonar.language parameter to triggering multi-language analysis
#sonar.language=java

# path to test source directories
sonar.sources=mypicker/src/main/java
sonar.test.inclusions=mypicker/src/test/java
sonar.java.binaries=mypicker/build/intermediates/javac/debug,ext/mypicker/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug
#sonar.junit.reportPaths=mypicker/build/test-results/testDebugUnitTest
#sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=mypicker/build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec
sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=mypicker/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/jacocoTestReport.xml
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.java.source=1.8
sonar.ws.timeout=300
sonar.findbugs.timeout=3600000
```

My gradle task code which works perfectly is:

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: 'testDebugUnitTest') {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def javaDebugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def kotlinDebugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories.from = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories.from = files([javaDebugTree, kotlinDebugTree])
    executionData.from = files("${buildDir}/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec")
}
```

Sonarqube: 6.7.5 (build 38563)
SonarQube Scanner: 4.0.0.1744

Comment: There should be some (SonarQube) (error)logging. Add the relevant parts to your question.